# How to use get() method of FolderListModel in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have trouble using the [`get`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html#get-method) method of `FolderListModel`. I have the following code:

```
FolderListModel {
    id: folderModel1
    nameFilters: ["*.png"]

    folder: "file:/home/***/template/"

    property int fetchIndex: -1
    property string hh

    onFetchIndexChanged: {
        hh = get (fetchIndex, fileName)
    }
}
```

This gives me the error:

> ReferenceError: fileName is not defined

What is the proper way to use that `get` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument type of the `get()` function is `string`, so the property name should be quoted. Also note that this function may return `undefined` that can throw during the assignment to `hh`:

```
Error: Cannot assign [undefined] to QString
```

Assuming that `fetchIndex` will be always changed only by non-negative values, it can be used as

```
if (fetchIndex < count) {
    hh = get(fetchIndex, "fileName")
}
```

Otherwise the index value should be handled externally to be less than the `count` property.